# How to deselect the weekend and holidays in date-picker using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery, I've created a date-picker, I want to deselect the weekend and holidays while end user click the date-picker button. Can you please suggest me how to proceed this?

**HTML**

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "d-M-yy");
  });
});
```

Please advise.

Comment: Might be this will solve your issue
http://www.spiceforms.com/blog/how-to-disable-dates-in-jquery-datepicker-a-short-guide/

Comment: Try using this - you can set the first element in the response `false` to disable the day. http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay All you need then is another array with holiday dates in it which you can compare with, to know whether to disable it nor not.

Comment: @Ankit, thanks, the problem solved.